# Json Array Pushes Data Twice to File Tree with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, amazon-s3, filetree

When pushing data into a file tree, it pushes 2 sets of the same data and I am not exactly sure why.

I have a simple json array that looks like this:

```
export const treeDataFile = [{
  type: 'directory',
  name: '2022',
  
}]
  export default treeDataFile;
```

I am trying to push 4 files I have into it like this by calling this function:

```
 const addFileToTree = (file,i) => {
      treeDataFile.push({type: i, name: file});
      console.log(treeDataFile)
      setFirstRender(true);   
 };
```

This is how addFileToTree is being called:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

 //AWS Setup 
 useEffect(() => {
   Amplify.configure({
     Auth:{
       identityPoolId: '',
       region: 'us-east-1',
     },
   
     Storage: {
       AWSS3: {
         bucket:'',
         region: 'ca-central-1',

       }
     }
   });
 },[]);
 
 //gets all files in the bucket
 useEffect(() => {
   Storage.list('').then(files => {
     const s3_files = setFiles(files);
     s3_files.replace("\"eTag\":", "\"perfect\":");
     console.log(s3_files);
     
 
   }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
   });
 },[]);

return (    
   <div classname="container">
  <GeistProvider>
    <CssBaseline />
  <Tree  style={{width:"280px", height: "500"}}  value={treeDataFile} onClick={handleShow} />
  </GeistProvider>
       <table>
         <tbody>
           {files.map((file,i) => (
             <tr key={file.key}>
              {addFileToTree(file.key,i)}
             </tr>
           ))}
         </tbody>
         
       </table>
   </div>
 );
};
```

The result has been this, there should only be 4 items, but it has duplicated it.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We can be strongly confident that `push` does what it is supposed to do, so that leaves the bug to be with how `addFileToTree` is used. You tagged React so can we see how that is actually being used within the component?

Comment: My magic crystal ball says you're using React's `StrictMode`, which runs component functions twice to ensure you're not doing anything silly in them... such as modifying a global `treeDataFile`. ;-)

Comment: Where are you calling ```addFileToTree``` can you share the full code ? seems this function is getting called twice ... and also no need to export ```treeDataFile``` twice ...

Comment: @BrianThompson @ Anup Added it

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this to work following AKX's method, does anyone have any ideas of what could be wrong? It seems that the "Component function", does not go through the (files || []).forEach.loop

Comment: The code in your "get all files" useEffect makes very little sense. `setFiles` returns undefined, so the rest is basically gibberish.

Comment: Strange thing is that it works fine with the old code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it spews an error into the console. Yes, as a side effect it does set `files`, but the replace stuff doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating the global `treeDataFile` as a side effect of your component function (and even "worse", as a side effect of a render `.map()`). Among other things, this would cause `treeDataFile` to grow larger and larger every time your component is updated.

You're also probably using [React's StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), which double-renders your components *to begin with* to make sure you're not doing anything silly, like you now are.

If your goal is to derive a `treeDataFile` for that `tree` component based on the global `treeDataFile` and `files`, you can do that with [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), which is a hook designed for deriving new data based on other data; in this case your "base" `treeDataFile` and the `files` you get. (I assume they're props, since you don't show. They could be state, too, of course.)

I elided the table from this component, since it didn't have any real content based on the original code you had.

**EDIT:** Based on the augmented code in the question, the expected types for everything become a bit clearer. For one, it's now clear `files` is an array of AWS Amplify S3 files, and that we're using Geist's Tree component. [A full, working example in TypeScript (without AWS Amplify, but with its types) can be found in this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so71740514-example-k4hy5i?file=/src/App.tsx).

```
const treeDataFile = [{
  type: "directory",
  name: '2022',
}];

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Load files via AWS Amplify.
    Storage.list('').then(setFiles);
  }, []);

  const treeWithFiles = React.useMemo(() => {
    const tree = [...treeDataFiles]; // shallow-copy
    (files || []).forEach((file, i) => {
      tree.push({ type: "file", name: String(file.key) });
    });
    return tree;
  }, [files]);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <GeistProvider>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Tree style={{ width: "280px", height: "500" }} value={treeWithFiles} />
      </GeistProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. It did not work right away with your code, but I'll try to use it and your explanation to get it to work on my end.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to React, for "files" i am using a state not a hook, would that change your code in any way?

Comment: added more details to my question code, it could be because I am using AWS to pull the data. error im getting while using your code: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, eTag, lastModified, size}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: I imagine `name: file` should be `name: file.key` in that case.

Comment: No files seem to show up when doing this. Do you have any other suggestions I can play around with other than useMemo?

Comment: @marcorivera8 Please see the edit (and the working example on CodeSandbox).